# error reading config.ini using configparser

Tags: python

I have a pydev project and in one of the packages I have a config.ini and a script.py

```
    project/
       package1/
           config.ini
           script1.py
```

config.ini has

```
[creds]
username=xyz
key=password
```

In script1.py I am trying to read this file and fetch the username and key attributes

```
import configparser
filename="config.ini"
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(filename)
print(config['creds']['username'])
```

and this gives me `*** KeyError: 'creds'` Any idea whats going wrong here?

I think it has to do something with config.ini path here.

Comment: Do you have any other `config.ini` files located somewhere else, that may be read instead?

Comment: No there is only 1 in that project

Comment: Just add some print functions/statements to find out what you are actually reading. `print(config.sections())` may show a lot already.

Comment: yeah I tried that `print(config.sections)
<bound method ConfigParser.sections of <configparser.ConfigParser object at 0x1349290>>`

Comment: Read carefully: there are `()` after the word `sections`.

Comment: aah sorry `(Pdb) print(config.sections())
[]`

Comment: So you're reading an empty config file. How *exactly* are you running script1.py?

Comment: python -m project.package1.script1.py

Comment: Probably, filename will then be relative to whatever directory you're in; are you sure that there's no config.ini in your current directory, for example?

Comment: Use something like `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.ini')` to obtain the path for the proper `config.ini` file.

Comment: I would also advise not to have a config.ini file in your package. Configurations should be user editable, so they should live in a user directory, not a package directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111818/discussion-between-love2code-and-evert).